# Overcoming KDDI's limitation for local E.164 numbers dialing

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I got my Toshiba IS12T from KDDI-Japan just a few weeks ago, and I faced a really annoying issue. It is not possible to dial a number within Japan using E.164 format (i.e. +81-....). The provider expects "local" numbers to be used when dialing within Japan. And this is a real pain, because my friends publish their phone numbers (on FB, for example) using the "global" convention.

Is there any type of API I can use to filter out dialing events, and modify on the flight the number being dialed? I understand that this is something the "Call Settings/International Assist" does. But how can I modify that assistance?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of adjusting the native dialling app programmatically. What you could do is create a small app which has a textbox and register the textbox's input value. Then, according to whatever has been inputted, adjust it to the correct 'local' format. You can then call the [PhoneCallTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394025%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and pass in the newly formatted number.

To select a number from your phonebook, you can use the [PhoneNumberChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394021%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). This brings back the number, which you can input into your 'conversion' function and then call the PhoneCallTask on that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try to follow your advice.